# The Shrine of Winter door will not open?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I killed all the bosses but the door will not open. I have beaten this game four times and I have never had this problem before.

I do not know what to do, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-requisite to open the Shrine of winter is to collect either 1 million souls, (an extra million per NG+), or collect all four great souls (Old Iron King, Lost Sinner, Duke's Dear Freja and The Rotten). You have to light the primal bonfires as well.

Comment: I have them souls Old Iron King, Lost Sinner, Duke's Dear Freja and The Rotten.And the door still will not open.