# Activating golems at the Drangleic Castle

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have to light the four Primal Bonfires but only one of the golems has moved at the doors to the Drangleic Castle. Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The golems are activated by souls. You need to kill the Royal Swordsmen as they pour out of the castle while standing near the gate, so that the inactive golem can absorb the souls from the Swordsmen when they die. This is why they spawn infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to start off, to get to Drangleic Castle you will need to have lit the Primal Bonfires to begin with, (there are [other methods to opening the Shrine of Winter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177881/the-shrine-of-winter-door-will-not-open/177894#177894), but that's for another time) so I'm not sure why that is in your question.

The doors to Drangleic Castle are activated by Souls. Specifically the souls of fallen enemies, that will be asorbed by the Golems standing either side of the doors. You'll find these fellows often throughout Drangleic Castle.

To activate them, you will need to kill an enemy near them. If it worked, you will see the souls float toward the Golem, rather than yourself. *You will not get the souls if this is done correctly,* so be careful who you kill!